# Selecting unique items from linked

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'am using `SQL Server 2012`. I have store, where different sellers place their goods. Different sellers can place same goods. For example. Two sellers can place 'iPhone' as article. I need to find unique goods in the store.
I have two tables:

1. **ArticlePlacedBySeller** {Id, Description, ...}
2. **LinkBetweenArticles** {Id, Article1, Article2 }

For example, if three sellers placed 'iPhone', and one 'iPhone 2' we will see:

> **ArticlePlacedBySeller**: {Id:**1**, Description:'iPhone super'}; {**2**, 'iPhone best'}; {**3**, 'iPhone new brand'}; {**4**, 'iPhone 2'}
>
> **LinkBetweenArticles**: {Id:1, Article1:**1**, Article2:**2**}; {2, **2, 1**}; {3, **2, 3**}; {4, **3, 2**}; {5, **3, 1**}; {6, **1, 3**};

As you saw, only first three goods linked between each others. Fourth article is **not linked**. Now we need select just one (no matter what exactly) of this 3 goods from **ArticlePlacedBySeller** and 1 not linked by part of description (*where Description like '%...%'*). (result of this script must be:

> **ArticlePlacedBySeller**: Id:**1**, Id:**4**

(two entities).

[Here is a script](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5caeb/1/0)

Can you suggest SQL query to do this?

P.S. Please don't suggest to change DB structure and add UniqueArticle table. I can't do this and this is unuseful because very dynamically changing of goods in store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work for particular case, but might need additional testing on bigger sample data. It also assumes your links will always be bi-directional.

```
;WITH CTE_Links AS 
(
    SELECT Article1, MIN(Article2) Article2
    FROM dbo.LinkBetweenArticles
    GROUP BY Article1
    HAVING Article1 > MIN(Article2)
)
SELECT a.* 
FROM dbo.ArticlePlacedBySeller a
LEFT JOIN CTE_Links l ON a.Id = l.Article1
WHERE l.Article2 IS NULL
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5caeb/2)**

**[Demo with few more articles](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa1c6/1)**