# Rewrite SQL to FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'am using `NHibernate 3.3.1.4000` and `FluentNHibernate 1.3.0.733` with `SQL Server 2012` and I need to rewrite query to IQueryOver to do this calculation on server side without stored procedure calling.

```
WITH CTE_Links AS 
(
    SELECT Article1, MIN(Article2) Article2
    FROM dbo.LinkBetweenArticles
    GROUP BY Article1
    HAVING Article1 > MIN(Article2)
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.ArticlePlacedBySeller a
LEFT JOIN CTE_Links l ON a.Id = l.Article1
WHERE l.Article2 IS NULL 
AND ConfirmedPosition_Id = 1000
```

Script description can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132949/selecting-unique-items-from-linked) if you need

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know it is not possible to use natively IQueryOver API to achieve this. IMHO you could use this CTE query as a custom query. You can find the solution by following the link http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-common-table-expressions-to.html.